# For what values of $p $ and $q$, this function is continuous?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I am not sure how to begin solving this.

> With *two* variables $p$ and $q$ that need to be solved for in order for all three to be continuous.
>
> $$
> f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
> x+p  &\mbox{ if $x \le 0$} \\
> x^2+q &\mbox{if  $0 < x < 5$}\\
> 6x+5 &\mbox{if  $x \ge 5$}
> \end{array} \right.
> $$

My intuition to start is that I need to check the functions at the points $x =0$ and $x=5$

For example $6(5)+5 = 5^2+q$ so then $q = 10$

For example $(0) + p = 0^2 + 10$ so then $p=10$. That doesn't make sense....

Any help to get me going would be much appreciated.

Comment: It does make sense, and is the solution. I assume that you mean that a function defined on those $3$ intervals should be continuous.

Comment: Your intuition is good

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)$ is a continuous function, so it is also continuous at $x=0$ and $x=5$.

So $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$$and$$\lim_{x\to 5^+} f(x)=f(5)=\lim_{x\to 5^-} f(x)$$

Now $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)\implies \lim_{x\to 0^+} (x^2 + q)=p=\lim_{x\to 0^-} (x+p)\implies q=p$$

Again $$\lim_{x\to 5^+} f(x)=f(5)=\lim_{x\to 5^-} f(x)\implies \lim_{x\to 5^+} (6x+5)=6.5+5=\lim_{x\to 5^-} (x^2 + q)\implies 35=35=25+q \implies q=10$$

Hence $p=q=10$